# Application stopps with Error inflating class android.widget.TextView afer updating to Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I was using the l-preview release to start developing an application that will target both Lollipop and devices down to Jelly Bean. After I updated to Android 5.0 through my SDK manager, I can't run my application. I get this exception:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:629)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:678)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:805)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:912)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:805)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:361)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2122)
        at com.navayo.secfone.PinEntryActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

When I delete the TextView from the layout it starts working. I don't understand what is the problem. Can anyone help?

EDIT: This is my layout...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="28dp"
    android:paddingLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialpad_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialpad_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/layout_delete"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:src="?clear"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_enter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/EnterStyle"
        android:text="@string/login_to_secfone"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="?enterColor"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am than using the layout with an "include" tag in my activity layout.. But this is where it stopped, the last TextView...

Comment: can you post the layout?

Comment: let's try narrowing down the issue. Can you delete style=" and android:textColor from the TextView and run it again ?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this. Tried it again now. Same thing happens... :(

Comment: textAllCaps and textSize ?

Comment: Yes, tried with that too and didn't work.. But I think that something else is the problem. I am running my application on a Nexus 4 device, with l-preview image. Now I ran the application on a Emulator, and did not force close. So maybe that was the problem all along.. Sorry I wasted your time and thank you for your trouble. I will try to update the image on my Nexus device and see if it works then

Answer (score 2):

Due to changes in  L, calling .recycle() twice or calling a getter on  recycle() is not safe. This has never been correct app behavior and prior to L may have introduced subtle errors.